# Fix umask for future RUN commands in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to fix a certain umask for all my RUN commands in the remainder of a dockerfile. Instead of writing this

```
RUN umask 0002 && do_something
```

I would like to do something like this

```
RUN echo umask 0002 >> some_file
RUN do_something
...
```

I have tried setting the umask for `root` in various ways but none of them seem to take effect on the following `RUN` commands. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Docker creates a new, minimal `sh` environment for every `RUN` step.

The umask is [set to 0022 in runc by default](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/2430a98e646a408003d1c327578ce602f6580cd4/libcontainer/rootfs_linux.go#L149) when a container is started. A `umask` configuration option has been exposed in `runc` but unfortunately that is [not configurable from Docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19189) yet.

For now, the `umask` command (or the process setting the umask) will need to be chained in each `RUN` step where it is needed, while the subsequent chained commands run under the same shell process.

```
RUN set -uex; \
    umask 0002; \
    do_something; \
    do_otherthing;
RUN set -uex; \
    umask 0002; \
    do_nextthing; \
    do_subsequentthing;
```

Comment: it seems umask is configurable now.(but not in dockerfile) https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/526d3b33742eaf502d8bf156ca794aae58ade8c7/libcontainer/rootfs_linux.go#L176   https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/main/config.md#posix-platform-user